# Mapping Exception in Collection saving as Member Variable in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, collections, persistence

Following Exception is coming why I don't know please help me to solve it

> Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: USER_DETAIL, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(listOfAddress)]

```
 @Entity 
 @Table (name="USER_DETAIL")
public class UsersDetail {

private int id;                                         //
@Column (name ="NAME")
private String name;
@ElementCollection
private List<Address> listOfAddress = new ArrayList<Address>();


@Id @GeneratedValue
@Column (name ="ID")
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public List<Address> getListOfAddress() {
    return listOfAddress;
}
public void setListOfAddress(List<Address> listOfAddress) {
    this.listOfAddress = listOfAddress;
}}
```

Comment: Could you also specify changes or ways you have tried to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Hi I think the issue is with the placement of annotations. You are using method access strategy (determined by @Id annotation). Put any JPA related annotation right above each getter instead of field members.

Like below:-

```
@Column (name ="NAME")
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

@ElementCollection
public List<Address> getListOfAddress() {
    return listOfAddress;
}
```